# How do I get the data attributes of divs and then passed along in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This may already been answred; however, I could not locate a particular solution.

Let's say I have following divs...

```
<div class="listings-area">

<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="">
<a class="listing"  data-id="D_2781467">blah blah </a>
some more blahj blah text here 
</div>

<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="">
<a class="listing"  data-id="D_2781445">blah blah </a>
some more blahj blah text here 
</div>

.......................
.......................
</div>
```

What I want is that I want to get all these data-id attributes and add to an array and then pass along in javascript cookie

If I do something like

```
$('a.listing').attr('data-id')
```

I get the data id of first element. I want all the element data id and then those ids added to an array...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

```
var idArr = $('a.listing').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-id');    
}).get();
```

then store it inside cookies using:

```
$.cookie("example", idArr);
```

if you're using **[jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)** plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.data()` to get data attribute:

```
$('a.listing').data('id');
```

to get all of them, use `.each()`:

```
var arr = $.cookie('somecookiename').split(', '); // split string to array
$('a.listing').each( function(){
   arr[i] = $(this).data('id') // convert string array entries to dataids
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourarray = new Array();
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('listing');
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ )
{
    var el = elements[i];
    var id = jQuery(el).attr('data-id');
    yourarray.push( id );
}

alert(yourarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map()` and `.data()` as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/iamnotsam/AExsP/

```
// Gets array of ids
var ids = $('.listing').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('id');    
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing is using for loop..
[Demo :](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/P6Ars/1/)

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="" class="ListingS">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="listing"  data-id="D_2781467">blah blah </a>
                <p>some more blahj blah text here </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="listing"  data-id="D_2781445">blah blah </a>
                <p>some more blahj blah text here </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
$(function(){
    var liLength = $('.ListingS').find('a').length;
    var liDom = $('.ListingS').find('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < liLength; i++ ) {
        console.log( "try " + i + liDom.eq(i).attr('data-id'));
    }
})
```